# How to convert strings of Year-Mon to the correct date format when exporting data in R?

Tags: r, date

I'm trying to ensure that the As_of_Dt converts to date correctly when I export the data from R as a csv. Currently, when I export the data to excel. It converts the As_of_Dt incorrectly. The month basically stays the same but the year becomes the day and the year becomes the current year (2020). If the as_of_dt is 18-Jan it becomes 1/18/20 in excel. I'm trying to prevent this from happening.

I would like this column to export like:
1/1/18 when the string is "18-Jan"

Currently, I tried

```
Data$As_of_Dt2<- zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(Data$As_of_Dt, "%y-%b"))
```

But there were some values that were NA in this new column I made.

Below you will find all the possible dates for the column As_of_Dt.

[image]

Update: I figured out that the date can sometimes be Jan-2018 or 2018-Jan. Is there a function that can convert these two situations into 1/1/18?

Comment: Can you use `dput` to show the example

Comment: If the `As_of_Dt` column be character or factor, could it be possible that some of the values have leading/trailing whitespace?  The most obvious explanation here would be that not all values conform to `%y-%b`.

Comment: Creating test data with `ym <- as.vector(t(outer(16:18, month.abb, paste, sep = "-")))`, the OP code works for me: `dates <- zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(ym, "%y-%b"))` followed by `format(dates, format = "%m/%d/%y")`.

Comment: I think the issue is that there are times when its year-month and times when its month-year. I'm not sure why this isn't reflected when I export the document from excel. Is there a function that can convert both situations into format specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.yearmon`

```
library(zoo)
as.Date( as.yearmon(dat, "%d-%b"))
#[1] "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-02-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-08-01"
#[9] "2020-01-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-06-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-05-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-08-01"
#[17] "2020-11-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-12-01" "2020-11-01"
```

If we have some mixed formats i.e. `%b-%d` along with the one showed in  the post, an option is to rearrange the substring with `sub` to make it a single format and then apply the `as.yearmon`

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(sub("^([A-Za-z]+)-(\\d+)$", "\\2-\\1", dat), "%d-%b"))
```

#### data

```
 dat <- c("20-Nov", "15-Nov", "20-Jan", "20-Jun", "20-Feb", "19-Apr", 
"16-Dec", "20-Aug", "17-Jan", "16-Jan", "17-Oct", "19-Jun", "17-Aug", 
"16-May", "16-Oct", "18-Aug", "19-Nov", "15-Jan", "17-Dec", "18-Nov")
```

Comment: I realized that there are two different situations one where the month is before year (Jan-18) and another where year is before 18-Jan. I think this is why this code isn't working for me. Is there an alternative that I can do that converts both situations to a date format?

Comment: This did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use `strptime`.

```
strptime(dat, "%d-%b")
# [1] "2020-11-20 CET"  "2020-11-15 CET"  "2020-01-20 CET"  "2020-06-20 CEST"
# [5] "2020-02-20 CET"  "2020-04-19 CEST" "2020-12-16 CET"  "2020-08-20 CEST"
# [9] "2020-01-17 CET"  "2020-01-16 CET"  "2020-10-17 CEST" "2020-06-19 CEST"
# [13] "2020-08-17 CEST" "2020-05-16 CEST" "2020-10-16 CEST" "2020-08-18 CEST"
# [17] "2020-11-19 CET"  "2020-01-15 CET"  "2020-12-17 CET"  "2020-11-18 CET"
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- c("20-Nov", "15-Nov", "20-Jan", "20-Jun", "20-Feb", "19-Apr", 
"16-Dec", "20-Aug", "17-Jan", "16-Jan", "17-Oct", "19-Jun", "17-Aug", 
"16-May", "16-Oct", "18-Aug", "19-Nov", "15-Jan", "17-Dec", "18-Nov")
```